# Kotlin setup on vscode

Tags: java, kotlin, visual-studio-code

I tried to setup the envirment following these steps :

- installing kotlin compiler and jdk and adding the binaries dir to sys path
  *installed the following extensions : coderunner, kotlin v0.2.31 and kotlin language ext

I kept getting the following error from code runner 'code language is not defined or supported'

VScode output

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Aug 29, 2023 11:54:27 AM org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint lambda$recursiveFindRpcMethods$2
SEVERE: A delegate object is null, jsonrpc methods of 'public default org.eclipse.lsp4j.services.NotebookDocumentService org.eclipse.lsp4j.services.LanguageServer.getNotebookDocumentService()' are ignored
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] main      Adding script definitions [null]
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] main      Kotlin Language Server: Version 1.3.3
[Error - 11:54:27 AM] main      A delegate object is null, jsonrpc methods of 'public default org.eclipse.lsp4j.services.NotebookDocumentService org.eclipse.lsp4j.services.LanguageServer.getNotebookDocumentService()' are ignored
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] main      Connected to client
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Adding workspace folder Kotlin
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Adding 0 files under c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\VS code\Kotlin to source path
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Searching for dependencies and Java sources in workspace root c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\VS code\Kotlin
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Could not resolve kotlin-stdlib using Maven: null
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Could not resolve kotlin-stdlib using Gradle: C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Found kotlinc.bat at C:\Program Files\kotlinc\bin\kotlinc.bat
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Could not resolve kotlin-stdlib using Maven: null
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Could not resolve kotlin-stdlib using Gradle: C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Found kotlinc.bat at C:\Program Files\kotlinc\bin\kotlinc.bat
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Adding [C:\Program Files\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-stdlib.jar] to class path
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Update build script path
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Could not resolve kotlin-stdlib using Maven: null
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Could not resolve kotlin-stdlib using Gradle: C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Found kotlinc.bat at C:\Program Files\kotlinc\bin\kotlinc.bat
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Adding [C:\Program Files\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-stdlib.jar] to build script class path
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Reinstantiating compiler
[Info  - 11:54:27 AM] async0    Adding script definitions [null]
[Info  - 11:54:28 AM] async0    Adding script definitions [null]
[Info  - 11:54:28 AM] client    Updated configuration: {"kotlin":{"java":{"home":""},"languageServer":{"enabled":true,"path":"","transport":"stdio","port":0,"debugAttach":{"enabled":false,"port":5005,"autoSuspend":false}},"trace":{"server":"off"},"compiler":{"jvm":{"target":"default"}},"linting":{"debounceTime":250},"indexing":{"enabled":true},"completion":{"snippets":{"enabled":true}},"debugAdapter":{"enabled":true,"path":""},"debounceTime":250,"externalSources":{"useKlsScheme":true,"autoConvertToKotlin":false},"snippetsEnabled":true}}
[Info  - 11:54:28 AM] debounce0 Linting .../Kotlin/main
[Info  - 11:54:28 AM] async2    Find symbols in .../Kotlin/main
[Info  - 11:54:28 AM] async2    Finished in 517 ms
[Info  - 11:54:31 AM] async2    Ranged semantic tokens in .../Kotlin/main
[Info  - 11:54:31 AM] async2    Found 15 tokens
[Info  - 11:54:31 AM] async2    Finished in 15 ms
[Info  - 11:54:31 AM] async2    Full semantic tokens in .../Kotlin/main
[Info  - 11:54:31 AM] async2    Found 15 tokens
[Info  - 11:54:31 AM] async2    Finished in 1 ms
[Info  - 11:54:32 AM] async3    Updating symbol index...
[Info  - 11:54:32 AM] async3    Updated symbol index in 31 ms! (1 symbol(s))
[Info  - 11:54:50 AM] async2    Hovering at .../Kotlin/main 3:1
[Info  - 11:54:50 AM] async2    Re-parsing main 0:1-3:2
[Info  - 11:54:50 AM] async2    Hovering BLOCK
[Info  - 11:54:50 AM] async2    Re-parsing main 0:1-3:2
[Info  - 11:54:50 AM] async2    Finished in 112 ms
[Info  - 11:55:07 AM] async2    Full semantic tokens in .../Kotlin/main
[Info  - 11:55:07 AM] async2    Found 15 tokens
[Info  - 11:55:07 AM] async2    Finished in 1 ms
[Info  - 11:55:11 AM] async2    Hovering at .../Kotlin/main 2:11
[Info  - 11:55:11 AM] async2    Re-parsing main 0:1-3:2
[Info  - 11:55:11 AM] async2    Hovering CALL_EXPRESSION
[Info  - 11:55:11 AM] async2    Re-parsing main 0:1-3:2
[Info  - 11:55:12 AM] async2    Finished in 1366 ms
[Info  - 11:59:01 AM] async2    Full semantic tokens in .../Kotlin/main
[Info  - 11:59:01 AM] async2    Found 15 tokens
[Info  - 11:59:01 AM] async2    Finished in 1 ms
```

I tried removing the ext and installing them back but still the problem persists`

Answer (score 0):

#### First the following need to be installed

- **Java JDK**: *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial*
- **Kotlin**: *https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases*

  *After unzipping, add the **bin** folder path to the system environment variables `path`*
- **Kotlin Language**: *https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mathiasfrohlich.Kotlin*
- **Code Runner**: *https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner*

#### How to run Kotlin in VS code

*Use the play button in the upper right corner or right-click to select **Run Code** to run the code*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to do all the mentioned steps but still encountered same message from the ext code runner 'code language not supported or defined'

Comment: How do you execute the code? Check in the cmd window whether kotlin is installed correctly.

Comment: I did check with 'kotlinc -version' on cmd output 'info: kotlinc-jvm 1.9.10 (JRE 11.0.19+9-LTS-224)', it is well installed

I execute the code via code runner using ctrl + alt + N which gives the mentioned error 'code language not supported or defined'

Comment: Show me your interface. or a gif.

Comment: First make sure your script file has `.kt` extension, then add the setting `"code-runner.customCommand": "cd $dir && kotlinc $fileName -include-runtime -d $fileNameWithoutExt.jar && java -jar $fileNameWithoutExt.jar",` and execute the code using `Ctrl+Alt+K`.